# How to call RecyclerView.Adapter from call a Fragment class?

Tags: android

I want to call RecyclerView.Adapter class from Fragment class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call adapter in fragments like this
 **declare your controls**

```
  RecyclerView fmRecyclerveiw;
  RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
  LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
  ArrayList<MessagePOJO> messagePOJOArrayList;
```

now in your **onCreateView** fragment method call or set adpter to your recyclerview like this

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);
    fmRecyclerveiw = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fm_recyclerview);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    fmRecyclerveiw.setHasFixedSize(true);
    fmRecyclerveiw.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    messagePOJOArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    init();
    adapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity(), messagePOJOArrayList);
    fmRecyclerveiw.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return rootView;
}
```

**in case of any query ask me**

Comment: thankyou so much ...but i want to know   cani call onBindViewHolder method from another fragment class?

Answer (score 0):

Refere [Android Working with Recycler View](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) for step by step documentation regarding recycler view implementation